# Nested for loops in r

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames.

`M` looks like this:

```
      vec_a vec_b vec_c
    A   0.0     0     0
    B   0.5     0     0
    C   0.5     1     1
```

`Rank` looks like this:

```
    rk_ini
    0.3333333
    0.3333333
    0.3333333
```

I would like to multiply each values in row 1 of `M` by the value in row 1 of `Rank` and add these products together.  Then do the same for row 2 and then row 3.

Afterwards I would like to concatenate these 3 values into a vector and column bind them on to the second data frame `Rank`. This should be repeated with the new values I just calculated to produce 3 more values to bind on to `Rank` and repeated whatever number of times I specify in the beginning of my function.  Continually binding on a new column on to `Rank.

```
## iterate t times to get rank
for(i in 1:t) {
  for (j in 1:(nrow(M))) {
    nr1[j] <- sum((Rank[j, i] * M[j, 1]), 
                  (Rank[j, i] * M[j, 2]), 
                  (Rank[j, i] * M[j, 3]))

    nextrank <- c(nextrank, nr1[j])
  }
  Rank <- cbind(Rank, nextrank[i])
}
```

Finally here are the results:

```
      rk_ini     nextrank[i] nextrank[i] nextrank[i] nextrank[i] nextrank[i]
    A 0.3333333        0     0.1666667   0.8333333           0           0
    B 0.3333333        0     0.1666667   0.8333333           0           0
    C 0.3333333        0     0.1666667   0.8333333           0           0
```

The results should look more like this:

```
      rk_ini     nextrank[i] nextrank[i] nextrank[i] nextrank[i] nextrank[i]
    A 0.3333333       0          ....
    B 0.3333333   0.1666667      ....
    C 0.3333333   0.8333333      ....
```

With each successive row in the new column being the sum of the products of the previous column multiplied by each value in the corresponding row in `M`.

I've tried numerous things and this last does not produce any errors, however it also does not produce the results I am looking for.  Any help you can provide in understanding what is going on here will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a vectorized way using matrix multiplication `%*%` and `replicate`:

```
M <- as.matrix(M)
R <- as.matrix(R)
mm <- replicate(5,R <<- M%*%R,simplify = TRUE)

        [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[2,] 0.1666666 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[3,] 0.8333332 0.9999999 0.9999999 0.9999999 0.9999999
```

Where M and R are;

```
M <- read.table(text='
vec_a vec_b vec_c
A 0.0   0    0
B 0.5   0    0
C 0.5   1    1',header=TRUE)
R <- read.table(text='
rk_ini
0.3333333
0.3333333
0.3333333',header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Calculating the row sums of the row-wise products of `M` and `R` is not a case of matrix multiplication, I believe. (i.e. `rowSums(sweep(M, 1, R, '*'))` is not the same as `M %*% R`).

Comment: This looks like what I want to do.  It is a matrix multiplication problem.  I didn't know that this functionality was available.

Comment: Thank you for this simple solution!  I'd still like to know how to make nested for loops work, but this was simple and straightforward.

Comment: @jbaums no problem. corrections(even wrong ones :) are always welcome.

Comment: Actually, I think my original concern was correct - this matrix multiplication produces elements `i` that correspond to `sum(M[i, ] * R)`, while @DR41 seems to be asking for `sum(M[i, ] * R[i])` ("multiply each values in row 1 of M by the value in row 1 of Rank and add these products together"). I think the output of @rnso's solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code as shown:

```
for(i in 1:t) {
            for (j in 1:(nrow(M))) {
            nr1[j] <- sum((Rank[j, i] * M[j, 1]), (Rank[j, i] * M[j, 2]), (Rank[j, i] * M[j, 3]))

            nextrank <- c(nextrank, nr1[j])
            }

            Rank <- cbind(Rank, nextrank[i*(1:3)])    **key step**
    }                

    Rank      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> M
  vec_a vec_b vec_c
A   0.0     0     0
B   0.5     0     0
C   0.5     1     1
> 
> rank
       rank
1 0.3333333
2 0.3333333
3 0.3333333
> 
> for(i in 1:4){
+ M$rank = rank[,length(rank)]
+ M$new = apply(M, 1, function(x) x[4]*sum(x[1],x[2],x[3]) )
+ rank[,length(rank)+1] = M$new 
+ }

> M = M[c(1:3)]
> M
  vec_a vec_b vec_c
A   0.0     0     0
B   0.5     0     0
C   0.5     1     1

> print(rank)
       rank        V2         V3         V4          V5
1 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000  0.00000000
2 0.3333333 0.1666666 0.08333332 0.04166666  0.02083333
3 0.3333333 0.8333333 2.08333313 5.20833281 13.02083203
>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then referring to the data in your post, you want the first element of your new `Rank` vector to be the sum of the products the first element of `Rank` and the elements of row `A` (i.e., `sum(M[1, ] * R[1])`), the second element to be the sum of the products of second element of `Rank` and the elements of row `B` (`sum(M[2, ] * R[2])`), and so on. You then want to repeat this calculation with the new `Rank` vector taking the place of the original `Rank` vector.

If this is the case, then I believe the output of the solution provided by @rnso is accurate.

Here's a vectorised approach that achieves the same, taking advantage of the fact that the nth operation for row `i` is equivalent to `Rank[i] * rowSums(M)[i]^n`.

```
M <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0,
              0.5, 0, 0,
              0.5, 1, 1), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

R.init <- c(0.3333333, 0.3333333, 0.3333333)

n <- 5
t(mapply(function(m, r)  r * m^(seq_len(n)), rowSums(M), R.init))

#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
# [1,] 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
# [2,] 0.1666666 0.08333332 0.04166666  0.02083333  0.01041667
# [3,] 0.8333333 2.08333312 5.20833281 13.02083203 32.55208008
```